# CSS - 'bleed' a div off the page

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div element 'bleed', contained within a fixed width centered page, to the left or right of the page?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no question is being asked.

Comment: What kind of sick bleeding is that? :/

Comment: Flagged for not being a question

Comment: SO is a question and answer site not a sharing one!

Comment: Else there's other ways : float : http://jsfiddle.net/gxG4W/1/ and dirction http://jsfiddle.net/gxG4W/2/ (it can be mixed :p

Comment: Never found an answer for this online before, thought I would help. @GCyrillus Very cool - Please submit as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `float` to align a box on either left or right side of container, it flow out the opposite way if it is wider that its container.
http://jsfiddle.net/gxG4W/1/

```
.bleed-leeft {
float:right;
width:100%;/* this will keep content within the width of container and give a scrollbar if needed */
padding-left:9999px;/* size you want to bleed out for your purpose */
}
```

You may use `direction` on parent and reset it on child, so it flows out at left instead of  right if body is LTR and vice versa
http://jsfiddle.net/gxG4W/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with.

The idea is to set a negative margin and a positive padding in the direction you want to bleed. If you set a negative margin to the right you need a container around your page set to `width: 100%;` and `overflow: hidden;`.

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/gxG4W/

HTML

```
<div class="body-hide">
    <div class="main-body">
        <div class="bleed-left">
            Bleed Left
        </div>
        <div class="bleed-right">
            Bleed Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.body-hide {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-body {
    width: 50%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.bleed-left {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px -9989px;    
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 9999px;
}
.bleed-right {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px -9999px 20px 0;    
    padding: 10px 9989px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Great Trick...I never would have tried that.

Answer (score 1):

This could be something as simple as denying scrolling on the Y axis.

For just visual effect, use:

```
div {
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how this would work? Could you show me an example?